# Compare image using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, compare

I am new to Matlab and I would like to use Matlab to compare the following pictures and find out the differences between them.

Real picture:

[image: Real picture]

Reference picture:

[image: Reference picture]

- First, the system should match the real picture and the reference picture
- Second, the system should match the modified picture with the reference picture and highlight out the differences.

Please advise on my doubt:

How can I match the similarity from two total different image? Should I selectively compare part of the both images? I have an idea using `histogram` and `normalized` to find out the peak match.

Thank you.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you without seeing your images. Can you post a couple of example images to see what you're talking about?

Comment: modified picture : http://postimg.org/image/r3upez3kt/

Answer (score 0):

There are many things people do. This is an active research area called image matching.

Sometimes people do template matching. Which is to match the entire reference picture to the real picture at many locations and at many scales. You can read more about this particular technique here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching